# Offsetting dataset to match another using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, alignment

I have a raster (raster #1) which looks like so

[image]

and a second raster (raster #2) like this

[image]

What I want to achieve using QGIS is **Fill in Raster #1's gaps with sensible values that have been influenced by Raster #2**

So to do so, I thought the process may be:

1. Offset Raster #2's z values by those of Raster #1
2. Use the `Raster Calculator` tool to then fill in the NULL/0 values of Raster #1 with the newly offset Raster #2 values which coincide in placement

I've tried using the `Raster Align` tool in QGIS to align Raster #1 and #2 with the `reference layer` being Raster #1. However, I'm not convinced it is giving me the proper offset values.

Can anyone recommend any improvements/better way to achieve what I want?

**Additional Info**
Raster #1 is a single-beam dataset whilst Raster #2 is a multibeam. Basically, my client wants interpolate the single-beam dataset (whilst keeping the original single-beam values as they are most accurate) to cover the areas which are currently NULL/0. They've asked that this interpolation be done using the multibeam data as the basis. This is why I had thought to offset Raster#2 by Raster#1 z values

Comment: Hi a bit more context would be good. Why do you need to offset the rasters? Do they hold data that still yields meaningfull results, if you shift them around? Or should they be indeed aligned, but are, for some reason, not alligened?

Comment: Hi @Vincé. I added some additional info to the question, hopefully that helps you to understand what I am *trying* to achieve